# How to create event handler for ASP control like Tridion control?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have an aspx page PopupReference. I am having Tridion control button and few asp controls too, like `asp:ddSelectOption` (Dropdown).

So in Popupreference.js as we are creating event handler for Tridion button I am trying to create the same for my asp controls as below:

This is Tridion button:

```js
c.InsertButton = $controls.getControl($("#InsertButton"), 
                                      "Tridion.Controls.Button");
```

This is my dropdown:

```js
c.ddSelectOption = $("#ddSelectOption");
```

Event handler for tridion button:

```js
$evt.addEventHandler(c.InsertButton, "click", this.getDelegate(this._execute));
```

Event handler for my dropdown:

```js
$evt.addEventHandler(c.ddSelectOption, "onselectedindexchanged",
                     this.getDelegate(this._ondropdownitemchanged));
console.log('eventhandler created');
```

I am calling the function :

```js
RTFExtensions.Popups.PopupReference.prototype._ondropdownitemchanged = 
                      function PopupReference$_ondropdownitemchanged(event) {
  Console.log('Initializing inside dropdown...');
};
```

But I am not able to see the last log anywhere, I think its not getting inside the function `ondropdownitemchanged(event)`. Does anyone have any clue how I can make this happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect your `onselectedindexchanged` event needs to be a `change`?

I've implemented something similar using a drop down, here are the pieces from my code. I hope this helps you to find your solution:

1) In the html / aspx page:

```html
<select id="systemDD"></select><label for="systemDD">Select a system</label>
```

2) In your JavaScript:

```js
var p = this.properties;
var c = p.controls;

// the the drop down items
c.SystemDropDown = $("#systemDD");
```

Adding the event handler:

```js
$evt.addEventHandler(c.SystemDropDown, "change",
                     this.getDelegate(this._systemDropDownChanged));
```

The method:

```js
EditorName.prototype._systemDropDownChanged = 
function EditorName$Extensions$EditorName$_systemDropDownChanged() {
    var p = this.properties;
    var c = p.controls;
    // get the selected system value
    var selectedSystem = $j(c.SystemDropDown).val(); 

};
```

I'd tackle it in the following ways:

1. When you get the dropdown element, check that you have it as an object
2. Try changing onselectedindexchanged to just 'change'
3. A strong alcoholic drink :)

Good luck

Comment: john ur trick always works for me. Thanks.. :) Option 3 was also not bad :) :)</br> having one question john , have you ever try to call core services in javascript, means if selecting one item in dropdown i need to populate all the publication in a list.can we achive this in Popupreference.js?

Comment: I wouldn't call the CoreService directly in JS, but rather create a Model that calls it. Have a read of Dom's blog post on the subject - http://www.dominic.cronin.nl/weblog/why-should-your-tridion-gui-extension-model-have-its-own-service-layer-on-top-of-the-core-service